# Parsing a date and time from a string in the current system format on Windows

Tags: c++, datetime, winapi

I need to parse a string that is supposed to consist of a date and time in the system's current date/time format settings. I can use, for example, [`std::get_time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time), but the problem is that I don't know what date/time format is set in the system.
I have found several ways to get the date/time format using:

`GetLocaleInfo`/`GetLocaleInfoEx` with `LOCALE_SSHORTDATE` and `LOCALE_SSHORTDATE`

or [`std::time_get<char>::dateorder()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/time_get/date_order)

but in this way, I get "incompatible format" with functions that parse date/time (`std::get_time()`) and it needs to be converted:

`GetLocaleInfo()` gives me `"MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss"`, and this needs to be converted to something like `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"`.

`std::time_get<char>::dateorder()` gives a more accurate order in date format:

```
std::time_get<char>::dmy
std::time_get<char>::mdy
std::time_get<char>::ymd
std::time_get<char>::ydm
```

but it is still necessary to define the separator and the time format.

In general, I don't mind manual conversion, but I'm wondering if there is a more direct way that gives the system date/time format that is compatible with the date/time parsing functions.

Comment: Parsing a locale-dependent datetime string is unusual. The primary purpose of the locale is for datetime *display*. If you need to store or exchange datetime values, it is common to use a locale-independent representation (such as [`std::chrono::time_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point)). If you do need a string, use a fixed, locale-independent format, such as [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: You could try VarDateFromStr https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-vardatefromstr

Answer (score 0):

[`std::get_time` uses the `std::time_get` facet.](http://eel.is/c++draft/ext.manip#lib:get_time)

[`std::time_get` uses the POSIX `strptime` interface for its flags.](http://eel.is/c++draft/locale.time.get#members-8.4.sentence-1)

The [POSIX `strptime` specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strptime.html) states that:

- `%x` The date, using the locale's date format.
- `%X` The time, using the locale's time format.

Whether or not this will actually work in your environment is another matter.  However, it is worth giving this a try.